# Java Arraylist of objects Contains/equals

Tags: java, object, arraylist, containers

I have looked at a number of places and most arraylist examples use "String" as their element, however places that use objects are difficult to find.

Let's say I am working on a book collection and I have an author object:

```
class Author {
  String name;
  <other data>;
  int bookCount;

  public Author(String n) {
     name = n;
  }

  public boolean equals(Author other) {
     if (other.name.equals(name)) { return true;}
     return false;
  }
}
```

So I create a list of authors instantiated as an arrayList:

```
Arraylist<Author> writers;
```

So I want to find out if an author exists and create a new entry if they don't or increment the bookCount if they do. I can write an equals method on the name in the Author (as shown above) and then do something like:

```
bookAuthor = "James Gosling"; // normally an input
Author current = new Author(bookAuthor);
if (!writers.contains(current)) {
    writers.add(current);
} else {
    writers.get(writers.indexOf(current)).bookCount++;
}
```

I believe that this will work, I find it objectionable to be creating a large number of objects just to throw them away after the comparison, but the problem I have is that the normal constructor for Author is not that simple, and involves a database lookup (so expensive).

This means the name only constructor can still be used in this case, but I then need to construct the Author twice. The only other way I can think of is to create a new class which inherits from ArrayList and overrides Contains and indexOf. Which seems like a lot of overhead and then do I need to override equals or hashCode or something else in the new class too?

Am I missing something, is there not some way of providing an inline function or something to make using containers of objects more easy?
I was hoping that one could do something like:

```
Arraylist<Author> {equals(String x) { if (x = this.name) { return true;} return false; } writers;

if (!writers.contains(bookAuthor)) {
    writers.add(new Author(bookAuthor,dbconn);
} else {
    writers.get(writers.indexOf(bookAuthor)).bookCount++;
}
```

but of course the contains and indexOf don't have String signatures, and putting that inline is almost the same amount of work as creating the new class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mybe you can use `Map<String,Author>` for name-> Author mapping,this will get it around

Comment: Are you suggesting a parallel Map storage or replacing the list? If the latter I can only extract a Collection object for the authors as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using real-world data, name is a terrible choice. How many John Smiths do you think there are that write books?

You need a unique identifier, and natural data won't cut it, so an artificial id field is the best option.

Next, you should override `equals()` to use id. `hashCode()` should be based on the same field(s) that `equals()` uses, so override that too accordingly.

Next, use a Set, not a List - sets maintain non-equality of their elements. No need to check.!

Comment: Thanks, but in my book collection (bit over 3000 books) I have no duplicate authors. It is a problem for the lookup though. As for set vs list, I still need to know if it is present or not to see if I need to add, or alter the data, so I don't see that as relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I had, to some extent, the similar situation a while ago, and I came over the problem like this:

1. Assign an ID to each author (or any unique identifier). *searching by name is time consuming after all*
2. Load all the data into a `HashMap<Long, Author>` : because it is faster to check the `HashMap` with all of the `Authors` in it, than checking the database every time.
3. In O(1) you can have access to the `Author` object you like by `hashMap.get(ID)`

Comment: Putting the data in a (Hash)Map loses the ordering of the List, but otherwise this is workable. If access is O(1) does it really matter if the key is Long or String?

Comment: Everything has its own pros and cons. No, it makes no difference whether you use `Long` or `String` as map's key.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, how about:

```java
class Author {
  String name;
  <other data>;
  int bookCount;

  public Author(String n) {
     name = n;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
     if (this == o) return true;
     if (o == null) return false;
     if (this.getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
     Author other = (Author) o;
     return other.name.equals(name);
  }
}
```

Changing the signature of the `equals` method with an `Object` class instead of `Author` so the `Arraylist.contains` method will be able to use it. But then you will have to cast the object to make the necessary comparisons.